# HP Laserjet P1108 Not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, printing, hp, laserjet

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I have HP Laserjet Professional p1108 printer.
Whenever I tried to print like print a test page, it show task completed, but no paper printing.

Printer is on network with Window 7 PC, so I connected it through samba

[image: Printer is on network with Window 7 PC, so I connected it through samba]

After connecting it is print a test page, but printer goes on idle state.

[image: printer is on idle state, stop printing]

Comment: How is the printer connected? Have you added it to CUPS, via `http://localhost:631`?

Comment: Printer is on network on Window 7 PC. I connected it through samba.

Comment: I added to CUPS but still its in idle State. Accpeting Jobs but not printing.

Comment: I have a 1020 (which I guess may be similar to the P1108, internally), and got it automatically detected and added to CUPS with Driver: HP LaserJet 1020 Foomatic/foo2zjs-z1 (recommended) (grayscale), Connection: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_1020?serial=FZ02HVZ, and Defaults: job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=one-sided. And also doesn't print. Just accepts the jobs, and silently "finish" them returning to Idle state.

Answer (score 0):

My HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125nw was stuck on Idle, and I solved it with the following steps:
(If you have already installed the printer, skip to step 3.)

1. installed the printer using the Printer program,
2. installed with the Install button within that program,
3. ran `sudo gedit` inside of the terminal,
4. then printed a page.

In my case, the sudo print with this printer selected initiated the automatic driver installation program. The first attempt did not print for me, but works after the driver installed.

Hope this helps.
-D